# How to integrate an expression inside simulink block between time t and t+T?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I wish to integrate a mathematical expression inside simulink block which looks something like this-

[image]

In order to calculate the definite integral whose bounds vary with every time step in simulink, I integrated the expression inside the integral using the integrator block of simulink and then added a delay block with time step T. I subtracted the value of signal before and after delay block. I wanted to verify if my approach is right or wrong?

PS: in the integral, capital T is fixed and small t is the time step of the simulink environment. Q and R are fixed matrices of suitable dimension and all other signals namely, x,u are available to me via other simulink blocks.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand we are talking here about two domains of integration:
1) "The Simulink domain", which integrates along *t*.
2) Domain of your integral with independent variable *tau*.
Unless you are able to mathematically convert your whole problem to a single domain, you need to introduce another integrator. In order to do so you can use Matlab Function block https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/creating-an-example-model-that-uses-a-matlab-function-block.html and calculate your definite integral using Matlab-supplied ODE solvers (e.g. ode45) or, if you consider code-generation and want to have more control, implement your own integrator (a family of explicit RK solvers are fairly straightforward to implement https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods).

If *x* and *u* variables are not constant along integration interval *t-T* to *T* (i.e. in your equation *x:x(tau)* and *u:u(tau)*), then you need to supply a callable Matlab functions, which calculate these variables. This, depending on the rest of your problem may not be possible (e.g. when *x* and *u* are signals integrated in your Simulink model).

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply, I believe the integration happens over only one variable.